# Office.JS: How to sideload Word/Excel Taskpane add-in with Office 2016 OnPrem?

Tags: javascript, excel, ms-word, office-js

Reviewing this:
https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/testing/create-a-network-shared-folder-catalog-for-task-pane-and-content-add-ins

Not quite enough information or exactly what we need. Here is the scenario. Customer is NOT on Office 365. They are only on Office 2016 on-prem. They want to create an Office.JS add-in for Excel and Word and have it mandatory load for all users.

How do we sideload a mandatory add-in across the enterprise? What are the registry keys or other information we need to provide so that Word and Excel will find and load the manifest to the project for all users?

Comment: I suggest checking out Nirsoft's reg change viewer. It's what I used to `sideload` an Add-In via `regedit`. But, note, it didn't work 100% on first launch, I think it required multiple launches to see/configure the reg changes and Office 2016 has limited capabilities w/ the Office.JS API. Honestly, I don't miss VBA, but the deployment I had setup was via OneDrive and a shortcut in `XLSTART` and it worked flawlessly. Office.JS deployment has been a nightmare, but I love coding in JS vs VBA! Good luck to you.

Answer (score 1):

David,

The only option you have for Excel and Word on prem is to use the Add-In catalog but this does not automatically deploy the Add-In or support Add-In Commands

Our only auto deployment mechanism for Word and Excel is Centralized Deployment but that's an Office 365 solution only

Thanks
Phil

Answer (score 0):

The reference document your are provided is for add-in testing purpose during development process or QA. Organizations should use Sharepoint catalog for Office line of products and Exchange applications catalog for Outlook add-ins. Available deployment options are described over here: [Deploy and publish your Office Add-in](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/publish/publish). For Excel and Word Office,js add-in you should look at: [Publish task pane and content add-ins to a SharePoint catalog](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/publish/publish-task-pane-and-content-add-ins-to-an-add-in-catalog).